# How can I execute a javascript file on sapui shell?

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I need to add the javascript to display in my shell. Is there a way to add a javascript in view.xml? Need help, I'm just a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the components of js file. The component.js file is the component controller and provides the runtime metadata and the component methods.

A component can depend on the entire SAPUI5 library. If you only require particular controls, you can also start with the corresponding require statements directly,
Refer [Link](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/27/ce0e4987cd426f8fa3e60836316428/content.htm)